# Ошибка асинхронности при запуске alembic

Tags: python, sqlite3, sqlalchemy, alembic

python 3.9, SQLAlchemy, Sqlite, aiogram 3.3
Пытаюсь создать 1 миграцию в alembic, даёт ошибку
raise exc.MissingGreenlet(
sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s)

В env.py прописан путь:
config.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", f"{DATABASE_URL}?async_fallback=True")
Перерыл весь интернет - ничего не нашёл.
Помогите разобраться

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался. Если устанавливать alembic сразу в асинхронном режиме -
alembic init -t async <script_directory_here>

- всё идёт отлично и в env.py:
  config.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", DATABASE_URL)